# My thread-safe queue code appears to work, any possible race conditions, deadlocks, or other design problems?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, mutex, condition-variable, unique-lock

I am new to using `condition_variable`s and `unique_lock`s in C++. I am working on creating an event loop that polls two custom event-queues and a "boolean" (see integer acting as boolean), which can be acted upon by multiple sources.

I have a demo (below) that appears to work, which I would greatly appreciate if you can review and confirm if it follows the best practices for using `unique_lock` and `condition_variable`s and any problems you foresee happening (race conditions, thread blocking, etc).

1. In `ThreadSafeQueue::enqueue(...):` are we unlocking twice by calling notify and having the unique_lock go out of scope?
2. In the method `TheadSafeQueue::dequeueAll():` We assume it is being called by a method that has been notified (cond.notify), and therefore has been locked. Is there a better way to encapsulate this to keep the caller cleaner?
3. Do we need to make our class members volatile [similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539824/problem-with-thread-safe-queue)?
4. Is there a better way to mockup our situation that allows us to test if we've correctly implemented the locks? Perhaps without the sleep statements and automating the checking process?

ThreadSafeQueue.h:

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
class ThreadSafeQueue {
 public:
  ThreadSafeQueue(std::condition_variable* cond, std::mutex* unvrsl_m)
      : ThreadSafeQueue(cond, unvrsl_m, 1) {}
  ThreadSafeQueue(std::condition_variable* cond, std::mutex* unvrsl_m,
                  uint32_t capacity)
      : cond(cond),
        m(unvrsl_m),
        head(0),
        tail(0),
        capacity(capacity),
        buffer((T*)malloc(get_size() * sizeof(T))),
        scratch_space((T*)malloc(get_size() * sizeof(T))) {}

  std::condition_variable* cond;

  ~ThreadSafeQueue() {
    free(scratch_space);
    free(buffer);
  }

  void resize(uint32_t new_cap) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(*m);
    check_params_resize(new_cap);

    free(scratch_space);
    scratch_space = buffer;
    buffer = (T*)malloc(sizeof(T) * new_cap);
    copy_cyclical_queue();
    free(scratch_space);
    scratch_space = (T*)malloc(new_cap * sizeof(T));

    tail = get_size();
    head = 0;
    capacity = new_cap;
  }
  void enqueue(const T& value) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(*m);
    resize();
    buffer[tail++] = value;
    if (tail == get_capacity()) {
      tail = 0;
    } else if (tail > get_capacity())
      throw("Something went horribly wrong TSQ: 75");
    cond->notify_one();
  }

// Assuming m has already been locked by the caller...
  void dequeueAll(std::vector<T>* vOut) {
    if (get_size() == 0) return;
    scratch_space = buffer;
    copy_cyclical_queue();
    vOut->insert(vOut->end(), buffer, buffer + get_size());
    head = tail = 0;
  }

  // Const functions because they shouldn't be modifying the internal variables
  // of the object
  bool is_empty() const { return get_size() == 0; }
  uint32_t get_size() const {
    if (head == tail)
      return 0;
    else if (head < tail) {
      // 1 2 3
      // 0 1 2
      // 1
      // 0
      return tail - head;
    } else {
      // 3 _ 1 2
      // 0 1 2 3
      // capacity-head + tail+1 = 4-2+0+1 = 2 + 1
      return get_capacity() - head + tail + 1;
    }
  }
  uint32_t get_capacity() const { return capacity; }
  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 private:
  std::mutex* m;
  uint32_t head;
  uint32_t tail;
  uint32_t capacity;
  T* buffer;
  T* scratch_space;
  uint32_t get_next_empty_spot();
  void copy_cyclical_queue() {
    uint32_t size = get_size();
    uint32_t cap = get_capacity();
    if (size == 0) {
      return;  // because we have nothing to copy
    }
    if (head + size <= cap) {
      // _ 1 2 3 ... index = 1, size = 3, 1+3 = 4 = capacity... only need 1 copy
      memcpy(buffer, scratch_space + head, sizeof(T) * size);
    } else {
      // 5 1 2 3 4 ... index = 1, size = 5, 1+5 = 6 = capacity... need to copy
      // 1-4 then 0-1

      // copy number of bytes: front = 1, to (5-1 = 4 elements)
      memcpy(buffer, scratch_space + head, sizeof(T) * (cap - head));
      // just copy the bytes from the front up to the first element in the old
      // array
      memcpy(buffer + (cap - head), scratch_space, sizeof(T) * tail);
    }
  }
  void check_params_resize(uint32_t new_cap) {
    if (new_cap < get_size()) {
      std::cerr << "ThreadSafeQueue: check_params_resize: size(" << get_size()
                << ") > new_cap(" << new_cap
                << ")... data "
                   "loss will occur if this happens. Prevented."
                << std::endl;
    }
  }
  void resize() {
    uint32_t new_cap;
    uint32_t size = get_size();
    uint32_t cap = get_capacity();
    if (size + 1 >= cap - 1) {
      std::cout << "RESIZE CALLED --- BAD" << std::endl;
      new_cap = 2 * cap;

      check_params_resize(new_cap);

      free(scratch_space);     // free existing (too small) scratch space
      scratch_space = buffer;  // transfer pointer over
      buffer = (T*)malloc(sizeof(T) * new_cap);  // allocate a bigger buffer
      copy_cyclical_queue();
      // move over everything with memcpy from scratch_space to buffer
      free(scratch_space);  // free what used to be the too-small buffer
      scratch_space =
          (T*)malloc(sizeof(T) * new_cap);  // recreate scratch space

      tail = size;
      head = 0;
      // since we're done with the old array... delete for memory management->

      capacity = new_cap;
    }
  }
};
// Event Types
// keyboard/mouse
// network
// dirty flag
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include <unistd.h>

#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <sstream>
#include <thread>

#include "ThreadSafeQueue.h"
using namespace std;

void write_to_threadsafe_queue(ThreadSafeQueue<uint32_t> *q,
                               uint32_t startVal) {
  uint32_t count = startVal;
  while (true) {
    q->enqueue(count);
    cout << "Successfully enqueued: " << count << endl;
    count += 2;
    sleep(count);
  }
}

void sleep_and_set_redraw(int *redraw, condition_variable *cond) {
  while (true) {
    sleep(3);
    __sync_fetch_and_or(redraw, 1);
    cond->notify_one();
  }
}

void process_events(vector<uint32_t> *qOut, condition_variable *cond,
                    ThreadSafeQueue<uint32_t> *q1,
                    ThreadSafeQueue<uint32_t> *q2, int *redraw, mutex *m) {
  while (true) {
    unique_lock<mutex> lck(*m);
    cond->wait(lck);
    q1->dequeueAll(qOut);
    q2->dequeueAll(qOut);
    if (__sync_fetch_and_and(redraw, 0)) {
      cout << "FLAG SET" << endl;
      qOut->push_back(0);
    }
    for (auto a : *qOut) cout << a << "\t";
    cout << endl;
    cout << "PROCESSING: " << qOut->size() << endl;
    qOut->clear();
  }
}

void test_2_queues_and_bool() {
  try {
    condition_variable cond;
    mutex m;
    ThreadSafeQueue<uint32_t> q1(&cond, &m, 1024);
    ThreadSafeQueue<uint32_t> q2(&cond, &m, 1024);
    int redraw = 0;
    vector<uint32_t> qOut;
    thread t1(write_to_threadsafe_queue, &q1, 2);
    thread t2(write_to_threadsafe_queue, &q2, 1);
    thread t3(sleep_and_set_redraw, &redraw, &cond);
    thread t4(process_events, &qOut, &cond, &q1, &q2, &redraw, &m);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();
  } catch (system_error &e) {
    cout << "MAIN TEST CRASHED" << e.what();
  }
}

int main() { test_2_queues_and_bool(); }
```

Comment: I think this question should be posted on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Improve code that you wrote or maintain, through peer review.

Your question must contain code that is already working correctly, and the relevant code sections must be embedded in the question. Please avoid stripping out key details that may be relevant to the review. If your code is incomplete or not working, you should ask for help on another site.

You may wish to mention specific concerns: performance, security issues, etc.

Comment: @rsjaffe This is specifically a question about correctness of certain issues with multithreading, and therefore seems more appropriate here.

Comment: We need generics of thread safe stuff so bad in C++.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Visual C++ comes with many concurrent containers like [concurrent_queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/concrt/reference/concurrent-queue-class?view=vs-2019). Creating concurrent collections isn't that easy. BTW mixing C and C++-style memory allocations (malloc/free with new/delete) is a bad idea that can easily lead to corruption

Comment: @MichaelDorgan C++ only recently got cross-platform mutexes and futures. Writing concurrent containers that are both correct and performant is far more difficult than taking a mutex during push/pop. There *are* concurrent libraries, like Visual C++'s concurrent runtime library, or Boost's shared and lock-free containers

Comment: @PMARINA instead of rolling your own, consider using Boost's [synchronized data structures](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/thread/sds.html). The linked page explains what's wrong with mutexes too. Synchronized structures still block though. Boost also has non-blocking structures in the [Lockfree](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/lockfree.html) namespace

Comment: Don't disagree.  This stuff is very very difficult to get 100% correct.  All you need to do is watch some of the stuff from the C dev conferences where the experts have had to redo their code year after year as edge cases are found.  While I work on a (non MS) compiler team, I don't want to worry about this stuff.  Too many ways it can go wrong.

Comment: The program looks OK to me, but kinda pointless. You don't really have a thread-safe queue - you have a class that, inexplicably, chooses to lock some mutex in some methods, but expects the caller to lock it in others. Why not just have the caller lock the mutex **all** the time, at which point you could use plain vanilla `std::queue` and be done with it?